# JS: короткая запись для выбора одного из нескольких массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы, условия

есть такой код для параметра компонента:

```
param = status === 'active' ? [r1, r2] :
status === 'inactive' ? [s1, s2, s3] :
status === 'completed' ? [t1]
```

а можно ли более компактно записать данный код?

что-то из серии:

```
param = [status === 'active' && ...[r1, r2], status === 'inactive' && ...[s1, s2, s3], status === 'completed' && ...[t1]]
```

Comment: Может `param = [].concat(status === 'active' ? [r1, r2] : status === 'inactive' ? [s1, s2, s3] : [t1])`?

Comment: @ΝNL993, ну по сути это как изначальное условие свернуть в одну строку - т.е. тут сохранилась if_else конструкция, а хочется иное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если цель - улучшить читаемость не прибегая к switch и вложенным тернарным операторам, то можно сделать через объект, например:

```
var statusesKV = {
  'active': [r1, r2],
  'inactive': [s1, s2, s3],
  'completed': [t1]
}

var param = statusesKV[status];
```

Comment: Да, вариант неплохой